# jsPDF and Salesforce Lightning Web Component

Tags: pdf, locker-service, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to create a Salesforce Lightning Web Component to create a custom Quote PDF using jsPDF. I mastered to use the external chart.js library with uploading it as a static resource, but when I try to do the same with jsPDF.js I always get a security error "SecureElement does not allow access to charset" while calling jsPDF.

Has anyone an answer to that or an alternative solution to create PDFs with Lightning Web Components?

Comment: Seems like jsPDF is not locker complaint . You might have to find alternative locker complaint workaround for  unsupported apis

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I thought so, do you have any hints for a PDF library that is Locker compliant? Thanks, Michael

Comment: May be you should try building like a visualforce for your requirement and then you can render natively on the platform or attach as a file .

Comment: @mohithshrivastava What about disabling locker by forcing your component to API version 39 [per this salesforce guidance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_ls_disable.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

I found this post because I am seeing this:

> SecureElement does not allow access to charset

working with a different 3rd party JavaScript library.

For me this is reported as a **warning** not an error and the JavaScript does load. Looking into this in the debugger, it is the `loadScript` call itself that tries to set this `charset` so I assume this warning will appear for any JavaScript loaded via `loadScript`.

Of course the JavaScript itself may still not work under the platform's security mechanisms... just don't be distracted by this warning.